# legacy code visual basic to c#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm building an c# app that is designed to replicate and enhance the functionality of an VB6 app developed many years ago. 
My problem is that one module in the old app does some realy complicated things and trying to replicate this starting from specs would be a big pain for me. Even if this sounds like the best idea.

My question is : is there a way i could keep the old VB module and integrate it into the c# app, so that i wouldn't have to rewrite everything ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the old VB module part of a DLL (or if not, could you isolate and compile it to a DLL)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You can turn the module into a COM object, and .Net will happily call into COM objects. Depending on what you have right now you may need to find a copy of Visual Studio 6 to make that happen (it's still available on MSDN if you have a subscription).  To give you more exact instructions we'd need to see more of your code.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio has a wizard that allows you to convert VB6 into VB.NET, which you could then reference in your C# project and use. However, this migration tool is no longer shipped with Visual Studio 2010 (it was shipped in older versions) Even still though, there generally is a lot of manual touchup work required, you are generally better off rewriting it by hand which could result in higher quality code, anyway. My recommendation to you is to rewrite the code, you can make touchups and make sure that it works correctly without having to go the COM/Interop route, but don't necessarily shun that option either. If rewriting all the code really is an issue, then interop is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COM` or export the module as a DLL. Here's some information for you regarding [VB6 and COM](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Article/19882).

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes, turning it into a com module, and calling it from your c# code. Whether this would be easier or not, I am not sure.

The problem is that this issue will not go away, and if there are changes needed to the module, or the interface, then someone has to do it. So practical yes, but consider carefully what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate the existing vb code to vb.net and compile it as a separate assembly and add it to the C# application.

Answer (score 0):

Can't VS2010 (maybe 2008) support both VB and C# projects in the same solution? If I'm not mistaken, they can. So you could actually convert your VB6 code into VB.Net and have the project in your solution with the C# stuff.